# Windows batch or powershell. Replace "{\n}" text

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I've got a text file that contains:

```
title
{
}
```

I need to replace {\n} with "mytext".

I tried to use this:

```
powershell -Command "(gc file.txt) -replace \"{\n}\", "mytext"
```

with no success.

Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Try `{\r?\n}` instead

Comment: Why `powershell -command ...`? Type the commands you want at a PowerShell prompt, not a `cmd.exe` prompt.

Comment: `powershell -NonI -NoL -NoP -C "(gc .\file.txt -raw) -replace '(?s){.*?}','mytext'"`

Answer (score 3):

- In order for `-replace` to operate *across lines*, you must read the *entire file* into memory as a *single string*, which is what `Get-Content -Raw` (`gc -raw`) does (PSv3+).
- Additionally, to account for the typical CRLF (`\r\n`) line endings on Windows, use `\r?\n` to match both them and LF-only (`\n`) line endings, as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) suggests.

Along with corrections to and simplification of quoting, we get:

```
powershell -Command "(gc -raw file.txt) -replace '\{\r?\n\}', 'mytext'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please view mklement0's answer instead for this question, as mine will not work. I will leave it here as a method of literal string replacement.

---

Give this a shot in a PowerShell console. If it works you can always save it as a script in a .ps1 file.

```
$FilePath = "\\Server\Share\PathToFile\File.txt"
$ToBeReplaced = "{\n}"
$ReplaceWith = "mytext"
$File = Get-Content $FilePath
$File | foreach { $_.Replace($ToBeReplaced,$ReplaceWith) } | Set-Content $FilePath
```

Comment: The first RHS operand of `-replace` is a _regex_, so `{\n}`matches a literal `{` followed by a (LF-only) _newline_, followed by a literal `}` (though, strictly speaking, the braces should be `\ `-escaped), the . You can't match that with line-by-line processing. Additionally, note that the `.Replace()` string _method_ performs _literal_ substring replacement only.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Always nice to learn the details of methods and what they can or can't do.

Answer (score 0):

Text file that contains:

```
title
{
}
```

Goal: replace {\n} with "mytext".

OP attempted:

```
powershell -Command "(gc file.txt) -replace \"{\n}\", "mytext"
```

First, Get-Content doesn't returned the NewLines (by default) but rather an array of strings split on the newlines so this is the most direct translation of the command you attempted:

```
(Get-Content file.txt) -join 'mytext'
```

Or use -Raw to prevent Get-Content from spliting and to just return one string:

```
(get-content -raw .\PSRLKeyBindings.txt) -replace '\n', 'mytext'
```

This works without using the Regex multiline modifiers etc. (I was uncertain that would be the case until I tested.)

If you really wish to run it from some arbitrary place (cmd.exe, Run dialog, called from a shortcut) then you need the "powershell -command" but if you just run it from the PowerShell console then you can omit that as above.

Here's the "starting PowerShell version -- though I use -noprofile because my extensive profile takes about 10 seconds to initialize:

```
powershell -noprofile -Command "(get-content -first 10 .\PSRLKeyBindings.txt) -join 'mytext'"
```

The quotes are necessary to make it all on "command parameter" -- or you can wrap it in curly braces -command { command here }